# Activity list is not showing in contacts after upgrade to latest civicrm 5.9.1

Tags: contacts, activities

Activity list is not showing in contacts after upgrade to latest civicrm 5.9.1

I enable SQL debugging and its shows last query:
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(tbl.activity_id)) as count FROM ( SELECT civicrm_activity.id as activity_id from civicrm_activity left join civicrm_option_value on civicrm_activity.activity_type_id = civicrm_option_value.value left join civicrm_option_group on civicrm_option_group.id = civicrm_option_value.option_group_id INNER JOIN civicrm_activity_contact ac ON ac.activity_id = civicrm_activity.id INNER JOIN civicrm_contact contact ON ac.contact_id = contact.id where ac.contact_id = 40023 AND civicrm_option_group.name = 'activity_type' AND civicrm_activity.is_deleted = 0 AND civicrm_activity.is_current_revision = 1 AND civicrm_activity.is_test= 0 AND ( civicrm_option_value.component_id IS NULL OR civicrm_option_value.component_id IN ( 1,2,4,5,6,8,9 ) ) ) as tbl LEFT JOIN civicrm_case_activity ON ( civicrm_case_activity.activity_id = tbl.activity_id ) WHERE civicrm_case_activity.id IS NULL;

Which means it return only count of activity  not the list.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you try clearing the cache first of all to see if that helps.  You can do this by deleting the files in the `templates_c` folder.  The location of this will depend on your CMS.  You can find more details in the [documentation on upgrades](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/).

If that doesn't help please edit you question to provide some more detail (including which CMS you are using).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. I got the answer if my question, it was because of custom code was written to override the tpl files and which was confliction with latest CiviCRM.I removed that and rewrite customization needed with latest tpl file and it works.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I'm glad you managed to sort this out.